# ios how simulate back button in a ViewController

Tags: ios, viewcontroller

i have more viewcontroller that start from rootviewcontroller.
So for example i start with controller A so pass to B and go to C the third.

Normally to come back we need to push back on left top.
Instead i want to know if is possible instead use back button by code come previus view controller that in this case is B.

to go on the next i use this

```
ViewController *sc = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];

    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:sc animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See UINavigationController popViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated

Answer (score 14):

Simples

```
[[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: if I have not navigationController, how can i do it rightly?